# Align this countdown to the middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this jquery based countdown timer: http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/

I am wondering how I can get it to align in the middle?

I have tried putting it into a container div that has text-align center on it, which doesn't work. What else can I try?

Comment: "No matter what I try" What _did_ you try? What part of centering it are you stuck on?

Comment: show us your code or make a fiddle.

Comment: <div align='center'>**countdown code**</div>

Answer (score 0):

try applying `margin:0 auto;` to the container div

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the body:

```
<div align='center'>**countdown code (the one that should be in the body)**</div>
```

It worked for me...